# commit changes to NEW directory in svn repository

Tags: svn

I checked out a version of source from a repository. I made a bunch of changes, and now I want to commit to a different directory int he respository. Is this possible?

I tried to make a working copy in the repository with the following command:

```
svn copy . myrespository.com/NEWdir
```

But my svn status in the working copy still shows a bunch of modifications, and svn info still shows the old dir in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

When the target of `svn copy` is a working directory, all it does is make copies of the original files into the new directory and schedules them for addition at the next commit. If you don't want to commit the changes to the original files then you need to revert them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Manually create a file of the same name under ur checked out folder under the same directory structure of the file u want to commit changes to as it is in ur repository. Copy the contents of the file which u made changes to into this newly created file and then commit the new file to repository

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand, but here goes: If you checked out a specific directory in the repository, you can only check your changes back into that same directory. That is the point of version control, no need to make copies or more directories. You can always revert back to an older version. If you still want to make a copy of the directory, maybe your best option is to create a branch.  See the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html) for more details.

If you accidentally applied the changes to the wrong directory (i.e. there was already two directories in the repository and you checked out the wrong directory), you can try this:

1. Check out the directory you actually want to apply the changes to.
2. Create a patch file with the changes from the working directory that you made your changes to (the "wrong" directory).
3. Apply the patch file to the working directory created in step (1)
4. Commit your changes of your working directory created in step (1)

This would only work if the directories (i.e. the one you made changes to and the one you actually wanted to make changes to) have the same structure + filenames. I would suggest rather making the changes manually on the correct directory, there's less chance of making a hash of it.